# Как в Apache ECharts скрыть label, если не помещается в свою линию?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Я использую Apache Superset, а для гистограммы - Apache ECharts. Отображаю данные со стилем - stack. Мне нужно отображать динамические данные (label) только в том случае, если они помещаются в свою линию, в противном случае скрывать. Как можно реализовать?

Сейчас это выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал добавить в series - **labelLayout: {hideOverlap: true}**.

Немного помогло, но проблема осталась. Это позволяет скрыть метки, которые перекрывают друг друга, но мне нужно, чтобы скрывались метки, которые не помещаются в свои линии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]